# How to store values in a servlet without re initializing them each time a servlet is called

Tags: java, servlets, web

I'm making a queue management system. I've hit on stump here. I'm letting the customer/user select their desired service whose token they want to get, but the thing is each time the servlet is called it re-initializes the service-option objects and the token number for that chosen services goes back to 1. How can I store the token count so that it doesn't goes back to 1 again.

```
public class XmlServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String Service_Option = request.getParameter("Service_Option");
            out.println("You selected Service is: "+ Service_Option);

    Customer_Console cc1 = new Customer_Console();
    Customer_Console cc2 = new Customer_Console();
    Customer_Console cc3 = new Customer_Console();

    if(Service_Option.equals("Cash Withdrawal"))
    {
        cc1.setConsole(1,Service_Option);
        Database_Manager.Insert(cc1);
    }
    else if(Service_Option.equals("Account Service"))
    {
        cc2.setConsole(2,Service_Option);
        Database_Manager.Insert(cc2);
    }
    else
    {
        cc3.setConsole(3,Service_Option);
        Database_Manager.Insert(cc3);
    }


    }
}
```

The Console class contains

```
private int serviceNum;
private String Service_Option;
private Token token;
```

and the setConsole method is

```
public void setConsole(int sNum,String sName)
{
    serviceNum = sNum;
    Service_Option = sName;
    token.incrementToken();
}
```

UPDATE

I'm having problems with dealing the session for more then 1 customer consoles

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);   
if(session == null)
{
   session = request.getSession(true);
   Integer count = 0;
   session.setAttribute("tokenCount",count);

}

if(Service_Option.equals("Cash Withdrawal"))
{
    Integer count = (int)session.getAttribute("tokenCount");
    count = new Integer(count.intValue() + 1);
    cc1.setToken(count);
    Database_Manager.Insert(cc1);
    session.setAttribute("tokenCount",count);
}
```

Also how can I reset the session that every time I restart tomcat I get started with the token number 1.
If I'm supposed to use only one session for all three consoles then how can I do that?

I tried with placing the console objects

```
if(session == null)
{
   session = request.getSession(true);
   session.setAttribute("cc1", cc1);
}

if(Service_Option.equals("Cash Withdrawal"))
{   
    cc1.issueToken();
    session.setAttribute("cc1", cc1);
    cc1 = (Customer_Console)session.getAttribute("cc1");
    Database_Manager.Insert(cc1);
}
```

But still it doesn't save the increments, again reinitializes the token, why is that?

Comment: Haven't read your code. Based on your question, I think you are looking for ServletContext object and Servlet Config.Search on how to declare them in your DD. Declared as <init-param> and <context-param>

Comment: @Neeraj Jain it's still it's not working. I keep on getting the nullPointer error if I do the following                                                       Customer_Console cc1 = new Customer_Console(); cc1.setConsole(1, "Cash Withdrawal"); HttpSession session = request.getSession(); session.setAttribute("cc",cc1); if(Service_Option.equals("Cash Withdrawal")) { cc1 = (Customer_Console)session.getAttribute("cc"); cc1.issueToken(); session.setAttribute("cc",cc1); Database_Manager.Insert(cc1); } I read up the link you sent but still it only increments once..what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Store Your `service-option` Object in `session Scope`  So every time your servlet it called you can access the Object using

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
Console service-option=null;
service-option=(Console)session.getAttribute("console");
if(service-option==null){
 service-option=new Console();
}
  // After doing your work(setting some variables etc)of Console Class Object 
  // you can set that Object in Session Like this

session.setAttribute("console", service-option); // here "console" is key
```

In this way it is  reinitialized only for the first time

As [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) Says

```
void setAttribute(String name,Object value)
```

> Binds an object to this session, using the name specified. If an
>   object of the same name is already bound to the session, the object is
>   replaced.

**Update**

A **HttpSession** is created when calling request.getSession() and it get destroyed/invalidated when you call `session.invalidate()` or `session timeout` occurs .

Now coming to

> Also how can I reset the session that every time I restart tomcat I
>   get started with the token number 1. If I'm supposed to use only one
>   session for all three consoles then how can I do that?

It will automatically get restarted but there will be no token number exist into it because it is fresh , if you need to access token number from your entire application then i suggest you to use [Servlet Context](http://www.javatpoint.com/servletcontext)

> An object of ServletContext is created by the web container at time of
>   deploying the project.This object can be used to get configuration
>   information from web.xml file. There is only one ServletContext object
>   per web application.
>
> If any information is shared to many servlet, it is better to provide
>   it from the web.xml file using the  element.

Now your another confusion

> I'm having problems with dealing the session for more then 1 customer
>   consoles

Please read [Session Management in Java](http://javapapers.com/servlet/session-life-cycle/) . As this topic is too broad so i have given you the link to read it yourself

Comment: This is request scope and not even valid Java.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply..can you show the storing part with an example, I mean how do u access the whole console object through the session?

Comment: would I need to make 3 sessions for the 3 customer console's

Comment: [Read the link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)  i have mentioned , you don't have to make 3 session you have to store 3 Objects of Console class into your session

Comment: Please see my updated question, where I tried out what you suggested

Comment: Customer_Console cc1 = new Customer_Console();
   cc1.setConsole(1, "Cash Withdrawal");
   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   session.setAttribute("cc",cc1);

   if(Service_Option.equals("Cash Withdrawal"))
       {
        cc1 = (Customer_Console)session.getAttribute("cc");
        cc1.issueToken(); 
        session.setAttribute("cc",cc1); 
        Database_Manager.Insert(cc1); 
       }                                                                                             I read up the link you sent but still it only increments once..what am I doing wrong here?